# Исправить страницу технического обслуживания

Tags: дефект, локализация, технические-работы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно, давайте напишем правильно:

> Обычно техническое обслуживание длится менее часа.

Comment: Зачем отправлять гулять пользоаателя на час, если работы например будут идти 5 минут? Время не определено.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, так ведь ситуация за 3 года не изменилась.

Comment: Угу. И метка "нет-в-Transifex" хорошо объясняет, почему. Если ошибка требует внимания разработчиков, ее исправления можно ждать неограниченно долго.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, я полагаю, строки, прописанные напрямую в коде, могут поправить Катя или Николас.